# Which is faster: manual processing of a single query in Java or doing multiple selects in SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Which should be faster?

1) selecting thrice on an SQL server and then adding the results into array lists on Java,

SQL Server

```
select count(1) from table where somecriteria = "true"; -- stmt1
select count(1) from table where somecriteria = "false"; -- stmt2
select count(1) from table; -- stmt3, values are either true or false only
```

Java

```
ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery();
while(rs1.next()){
    arrayList1.add(someKeyGeneratingMethod1());
}
ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery();
while(rs2.next()){
    arrayList2.add(someKeyGeneratingMethod2());
}
ResultSet rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery();
while(rs3.next()){
    arrayList3.add(someKeyGeneratingMethod3());
}
```

or, 2) selecting once using SQL Server and then processing the results one by one into array lists on Java?

SQL Server

```
select count(1) from table; -- stmt, values are either true or false only
```

Java

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    String x = rs.getString(1);
    if("true".equals(x)){
        arrayList1.add(someKeyGeneratingMethod1());
    } else {
        arrayList2.add(someKeyGeneratingMethod2());
    }
    arrayList3.add(someKeyGeneratingMethod3());
}
```

Comment: Always better to have less number of network communications between Java and SQL...

Comment: second approach is good.

Comment: use `select count(column1),column1 from table_name where condition group by column1`

Comment: @user3218114 will `select count(column1),column1 from table group by column1` be faster than the second approach?

Comment: you need to return the value of column1 along with count to check it in the code. the query that you shared will not work. `rs.getString(1)` will return count not `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is just 3 counts there is no need to execute 3 statements using java. It will slow down the process in oppose to getting it from one query and processing inside java. This is because executing an SQL statement using java has it's own workflow and you'll be invoking this workflow 3 times.